# TYPO3 page translation not working. It showing error in Free mode and custom elements are not translated in ConnectedMode

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have some problems regarding the page translation on one of my websites which contains 2 languages.
German is the default and English is the next one.
Following is the site configuration.

```
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
    websiteTitle: ''
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_EN.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: en-us-gb
    languageId: 1
rootPageId: 1
```

1. In the **Free mode** of translation, the Custom element for my banner showing [this error](https://prnt.sc/xowg0p).
2. In **Connected mode**, only the normal text in RTE is translated. Custom content elements are showing the default german itself

If anyone has any idea about this kindly help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a general tip: 1. add error messages as text so that they are searchable (other people who have the same or similar problem might find the question as well) 2. Put all the information inline into a question so that it is still useful if external resources are no longer available.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: The error looks like there is some problem with files in your custom content elements. You might want to look at the complete exception trace in case that helps. If you can, debug the problem in the ViewHelper. In any case, this does not sound like a general TYPO3 problem. You should not get this type of problem in a standard TYPO3 installation. (might still be useful to post your TYPO3 version as well). As far as I can tell, we might need more information here to help (code of your custom CE).

Comment: Hi @SybillePeters, Thanks for your reply.
Sure I will post my error message as text from now onwards. 
regarding the issue, I have followed the proper ways of content element creation of TYPO3 version 10. The same method I followed in other sites too and this kind of issue is not there. I couldn't find what's wrong with this and I totally stuck in this. can you help me to find this!!

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have fixed my issue. I have used a Custom Viewhelper for fetching the data from the table. And there were some mistakes in that.

Thank you!